# Prevent FlatList from re-rendering entire list when state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have an array of `posts` in a redux reducer that I update via the `onEndReached` prop of my `FlatList`. The issue is, every time the state changes, the entire list is re-rendered rather than the affected post item.

```
// Posts Feed Screen

const posts = useSelector(state => state.posts)

const renderItem = useCallback(
    ({ item }) => (
        <Post post={item} />
    ),
    []
)
const keyExtractor = useCallback(
    (item, index) => `${item.id}${index}`,
    []
)

return (
    <FlatList
        ref={ref}
        data={posts}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        onEndReached={onEndReached}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.6}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        removeClippedSubviews
    />
)



// Post Component

const Post = ({ post }) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.post}>
            <PostHeader />
            <View style={styles.postBody}>
                <PostContent />
                <PostFooter />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

const isEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
    return prevProps.post.id === nextProps.post.id
}

export default React.memo(Post, isEqual)
```

As you can see, I'm utilizing `useCallback` on `renderItem` function, also using `React.memo` on the export of my `Post Component` - however, the `FlatList` still renders every post item on state change.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I do not understand how do you exactly expect that react will rerender a specific post in the FlatList when you senf the entire post list as props...I dont think that in this case you can expect from the virtual DOM to rerender only the changed post. But I might be wrong...

Comment: This is actually simpler than it seems.  What happens is that when you pass "reference types" as props everytime a new reference is created the component will re-render. So in your reducer that updates the posts you should make sure you are not creating a new list every time but rather updating only properties of a single post within the list. Avoid spread operator for example. Also the post component should not take a post as a prop but actually an Id of the post and find it itslef using the useSelector which returns the values of the properties.

Comment: So for example it is better to have a useSelector per property being displayed than a single useSelector for the whole post.  The reason is that the react rendering engine compares using "==" to find differences and decide how to render.  And two objects can be exactly the same but return as different because they are different instances

Comment: I have had this problem many times in the past and I have been able to solve the rendering problem 100% of the time. If you want to contact me private we can talk and I can show you some examples.  I am in charge of React apps that have such complexity that rendering can make the app unusable so I have a lot experience with this.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro so your advice on refactoring how I update my reducer and getting  away from the spread operator is what fixed it. Rather than spreading at every level, I simply updated specific post item and that did it!

Comment: @JohnJackson I have posted some of my comments as answers just to make sure others can benefit when searching online.  You are free to add the code you came up with as an answer or perhaps as an edit to my answer. I am glad I could help you because React rendering can be quite challenging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to post my comments as an answer because ultimately that is how the problem was solved:

This is actually simpler than it seems. What happens is that when you pass "reference types" as props everytime a new reference is created the component will re-render.

So in your reducer that updates the "posts" you should make sure you are not creating a new list every time but rather updating only properties of a single post within the list.

Avoid spread operator for example. Also the post component should not take a post as a prop but actually an Id of the post and find it itself using the useSelector which in turn should return values of the properties.

So for example it is better to have a useSelector per property being displayed than a single useSelector for the whole post.
The reason is that the react rendering engine compares using "==" to find differences and decide how to render.

And two objects can be exactly the same compared property by property, but yet return as different because they are different instances.

The key here is to only update the properties that need updating inside the reducers and at the same time make sure you return value types in your useSelectors.

Comment: where is the code for your solution?

Comment: what about when you delete one post from the list? Will it re-render the whole flatlist again? Is that an expected behaviour?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro sorry, how can you be updating an existing post if redux states (and I quote): "One of the primary rules of Redux is that our reducers are never allowed to mutate the original / current state values!"

Comment: @Dieguinho what triggers the re-render is the comparison of the value returned by useSelector... so even if you create a new instance of the post using a spread operator there wont be a triggered render pass unless the properties are different.  the data source should not be the array but rather the individual posts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering how you used the keyExtractor function. In react conciliation algorithm, key plays an important role as you can see from [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys).
If all your post components are rendered every time, please consider the following situations.

**use of keyExtractor**

If key is unique in the siblings and remains same across rendering, React won't redraw the post with the same key as previous posts(in the previous rendering). If key is not unique, unexpected result would happen, and if key is changing every render, all posts would re-rendered.

In your code, keyExtractor combines the id and index. What if post order changed? key would be different even for the same post if its order is not same as before. This might be a problem. If your post id isn't changed and unique among posts, you can use id as key. That's the common way to find keys.

**conditional rendering**

I don't know your FlatList component implementation details. If this component draws the posts in some cases and doesn't in other cases, React would re-render all posts even though they have unique and not-changed keys.

Other reasons may exist, but I hope these possible cases would help you. Below are my abstract code.

```
FlatList:
const { 
    data,
    keyExtractor,
    renderItem: Component,
    ...
} = props;

return (
    <>
        {data && data.map((post, index) => (
            <Component key={keyExtractor(post)} item={post} />
        ))}
    </>
)

// Posts Feed Screen
const renderItem = useCallback(
    ({ item }) => (
      <Post post={item} />
    ),
    []
)

const keyExtractor = useCallback(
    (item, index) => `${item.id}`,
    []
  )
```

Comment: solid point about the key extractor. I'm memoizing my list items too but my list also has a sorting function. If I use the index as a key, this will change every time and thus all items will be re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

const onEndReached = async () => {
    await MyApi().getPosts()
    .then(newPosts => {
        setPosts([...posts, ...newPosts]);
    })
}
```